# No sound on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.5 system with Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: audio, ubuntu-18.04, alsa, pulseaudio

I've had some trouble with sound for a few weeks already, it just doesn't produce any output on my system. I've tried submitting a bug report, but there is no answer from launchpad, the bug importance is undecided and it is not assigned to anyone. I have used Ubuntu 18.04 before and had no trouble with sound.

So, I've decided to reinstall Ubuntu in hope that the issue gets fixed, but that did not happen.   I would really want to solve the problem, but I don't know how. I've looked up a lot of things and tried them, but nothing works...

Things I've tried:

- Playing around with alsamixer
- Playing around with pavucontrol and pulseaudio
- Reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio
- Doing alsa force-reload
- Adding `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- Adding `blacklist snd_soc_skl` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I kindly ask for help.

I am posting relevant outputs below:

**$ sudo lshw -C sound**

```
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:88 memory:fc080000-fc083fff
  *-multimedia:0
       description: Audio device
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:90 memory:fc5c8000-fc5cbfff
  *-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.5
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.5
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc580000-fc5bffff
  *-multimedia:2
       description: Audio device
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.6
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.6
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:91 memory:fc5c0000-fc5c7fff
```

**$ inxi -SMA**

```
System:    Host: fortminor Kernel: 5.4.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Zephyrus G15 GA502IV_GA502IV v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GA502IV v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: GA502IV.207 date: 08/03/2020
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 15e3 driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 1637 driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 NVIDIA Device 10f9 driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.4.0-45-generic
```

**$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel**

```
snd_hda_intel          49152  15
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm               102400  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                    86016  37 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

**$ lsmod | grep snd_**

```
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  2
snd_hda_intel          49152  10
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm               102400  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_pci_acp3x          16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  3 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  29 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

**$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/***

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm        1472 F.... pulseaudio
                     fortminor   2067 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  gdm        1472 F.... pulseaudio
                     fortminor   2067 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC2:  fortminor   2067 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p:   fortminor   2067 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/timer:      fortminor   2067 f.... pulseaudio
```

**$ pacmd list-cards**

```
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 88"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "10f9"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c8000 irq 90"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "1637"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 30
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 91"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo/#1: HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo/#2: HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (priority 8800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

**$ pacmd list-sinks**

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 35574 /  54% / -15,92 dB,   front-right: 35574 /  54% / -15,92 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 92,62 ms
    max request: 17 KiB
    max rewind: 17 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 4
    linked by: 4
    fixed latency: 100,14 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6>
    module: 30
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC294 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC294 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 91"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "15e3"
        device.string = "front:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC294"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0294,10431e11,00100004"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

**$ pacmd list-sink-inputs**

```
4 sink input(s) available.
    index: 2
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: 
    state: DRAINED
    sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo>
    volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    requested latency: 100,14 ms
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: speex-float-1
    module: 12
    client: 13 <speech-dispatcher>
    properties:
        media.name = "playback"
        application.name = "speech-dispatcher"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "2854"
        application.process.user = "fortminor"
        application.process.host = "fortminor"
        application.process.binary = "sd_espeak-ng"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":1"
        application.process.machine_id = "f36f639ed8654c06b71f38dd593b6bba"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:speech-dispatcher"
    index: 3
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: 
    state: DRAINED
    sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo>
    volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    requested latency: 100,14 ms
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: speex-float-1
    module: 12
    client: 14 <speech-dispatcher>
    properties:
        media.name = "playback"
        application.name = "speech-dispatcher"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "2864"
        application.process.user = "fortminor"
        application.process.host = "fortminor"
        application.process.binary = "sd_dummy"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":1"
        application.process.machine_id = "f36f639ed8654c06b71f38dd593b6bba"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:speech-dispatcher"
    index: 4
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: 
    state: DRAINED
    sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo>
    volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    requested latency: 100,14 ms
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    resample method: speex-float-1
    module: 12
    client: 15 <speech-dispatcher>
    properties:
        media.name = "playback"
        application.name = "speech-dispatcher"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "2869"
        application.process.user = "fortminor"
        application.process.host = "fortminor"
        application.process.binary = "sd_generic"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":1"
        application.process.machine_id = "f36f639ed8654c06b71f38dd593b6bba"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:speech-dispatcher"
    index: 16
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: START_CORKED 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 120,81 ms
    requested latency: 100,14 ms
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: copy
    module: 12
    client: 11 <Firefox>
    properties:
        media.name = "AudioStream"
        application.name = "Firefox"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "2371"
        application.process.user = "fortminor"
        application.process.host = "fortminor"
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":1"
        application.process.machine_id = "f36f639ed8654c06b71f38dd593b6bba"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Firefox"
```

**EDIT:**

- `/etc/libao.conf` contains pulse as default driver (`default_driver=pulse`)
- `$ systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket` produces no output
- `$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio` output:

> ```
>  pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
>    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-19 21:41:33 MSK; 5min ago
>  Main PID: 1708 (pulseaudio)
>    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/pulseaudio.service
>            ├─1708 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
>            └─1715 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulse/gconf-helper
>
> сен 19 21:41:33 fortminor systemd[1696]: Starting Sound Service...
> сен 19 21:41:33 fortminor systemd[1696]: Started Sound Service.
> сен 19 21:41:34 fortminor pulseaudio[1708]: E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.free
> ```

But there is no sound still.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Ask Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pulseaudio

1. Ensure the /etc/libao.conf defaults to pulseaudio

   default_driver=pulse

   [or edit or create a local .libao (note the dot as the first character) file in your
   home directory (this will take precedence over the /etc/libao.conf file which is system wide)]
2. Ensure that the pulseaudio daemon is enabled

   systemctl --user enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket

The check pulse audio:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio
```

**Edit**
It's been report that `speech-dispatcher` sometimes breaks audio
try editing `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher`
change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`
or
if you don't use it, remove it.

Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218058/ubuntu-19-10-audio-driver-issue
which resolves a similar issue by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
namely adding
`options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my question with the relevant outputs. It seems active and working, but there is no sound still... What shall I do now?

Comment: Seems a bit daft to ask, given the effort you've put into the question `but` has it ever worked and if so, did you change anything immediately prior to it stopping?

Comment: I understand why that comes on to your mind :) I remember there was some system update after which it broke, but I have reinstalled the Ubuntu system afterwards, so it’s pretty much happening on a fresh system. I know that it all seems very weird, indeed it is weird. It kind of unrelated, but I’ve had similar issue with wi-fi on Ubuntu, it broke out of nowhere, but the issue was that Windows had a fast boot enabled, even though it was working before that too. Do you think it’s possible that Windows breaks that too?

Comment: By the way, I thank you for spending you own time on trying to help me. No one has made a suggestion for that problem in a long time, no matter where I post :)

Comment: See my edit for my last throw of the dice and remember that all your hacking may have made it worse. At some point you may need to reinstall alsa and pulseaudio.

Comment: I don't know how that got fixed, I just downloaded ubuntu again and reinstalled it, and it worked... Though what Rolf suggested makes sense and should fix the problem anyways. Thanks a lot!